# Pytest - how to order test execution in parametrized tests by parameter first

Tags: python, python-3.x, testing, pytest, parametrized-testing

I have the following parametrized test:

```
import pytest
@pytest.mark.parametrize("url1", ["url0001", "url0002", "url0003"], indirect=False)
class Test01:
    def test01(self, url1):
        print(url1)
        assert url1 == f"{url1}"


    def test02(self, url1):
        print(url1)
        assert url1 == f"{url1}"
```

**Result:**

```
venv/test_url_fixt.py::Test01::test01[url0001] PASSED                    [ 16%]url0001

venv/test_url_fixt.py::Test01::test01[url0002] PASSED                    [ 33%]url0002

venv/test_url_fixt.py::Test01::test01[url0003] PASSED                    [ 50%]url0003

venv/test_url_fixt.py::Test01::test02[url0001] PASSED                    [ 66%]url0001

venv/test_url_fixt.py::Test01::test02[url0002] PASSED                    [ 83%]url0002

venv/test_url_fixt.py::Test01::test02[url0003] PASSED                    [100%]url0003


============================== 6 passed in 0.03s ==============================

Process finished with exit code 0
```

**Target result:**

```
venv/test_url_fixt.py::Test01::test01[url0001] PASSED                    [ 16%]url0001

venv/test_url_fixt.py::Test01::test02[url0001] PASSED                    [ 33%]url0001

venv/test_url_fixt.py::Test01::test01[url0002] PASSED                    [ 50%]url0002

venv/test_url_fixt.py::Test01::test02[url0002] PASSED                    [ 66%]url0002

venv/test_url_fixt.py::Test01::test01[url0003] PASSED                    [ 83%]url0003

venv/test_url_fixt.py::Test01::test02[url0003] PASSED                    [100%]url0003


============================== 6 passed in 0.03s ==============================

Process finished with exit code 0
```

**Info:**
I just need to execute `test01` with `url1` = "url0001" and `test02` with `url1` = "url0001" first, then loop over all tests with the next parameter, e.g. `test01` with `url1` = "url0002", `test02` with `url1` = "url0002" and so on. I have the list of urls and want to execute properly set of tests with that list of urls.

**update**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from allure_commons.types import AttachmentType
import pytest
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
import time
import logging
import allure


driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe')


# Logger

logging.basicConfig(filename="C:/LPsLogs/test.log",
                    format='%(asctime)s: %(levelname)s: %(message)s',
                    datefmt='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')


logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)


wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
driver.implicitly_wait(5)

ec = EC
goxp = driver.find_element_by_xpath
goid = driver.find_element_by_id
keys = Keys
original_window = driver.current_window_handle

# Urls
sslurl = "https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html"


# Locators

# xpath
sslpch = "//h1"
u1chb1 = "//div[@id='checkData']/descendant::td[1]"
u1chb2 = "//div[@id='checkData']/descendant::td[3]"
u1chb3 = "//div[@id='checkData']/descendant::td[5]"
u1chb4 = "//div[@id='checkData']/descendant::td[7]"
u1chb5 = "//div[@id='checkData']/descendant::td[11]"
u1chb6 = "//div[@id='checkData']/descendant::td[15]"

# id
hostname = "hostname"
expdate = "cert_expiration_days"


@allure.severity(allure.severity_level.BLOCKER)
def test_go_sslcheck():
    logger.info("Testing started")
    driver.maximize_window()
    driver.get(sslurl)
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, sslpch)))
    sslchecker = driver.find_element_by_xpath(sslpch).text
    if sslchecker == 'SSL Checker':
        assert True
    else:
        logging.error('Error - def test_go_sslcheck module', exc_info=True)
        allure.attach(driver.get_screenshot_as_png(), name="testLoginScreen", attachment_type=AttachmentType.PNG)
        assert False


@pytest.mark.parametrize("url", ["google.com",
                                 "https://expired.badssl.com"
                                 ])
class TestSSL:

    @allure.severity(allure.severity_level.CRITICAL)
    def test_url_input(self, url):
        try:
            input_hostname = goid(hostname)
            input_hostname.send_keys(url)
            input_hostname.send_keys(keys.ENTER)
            time.sleep(2)
            print(f"{url} has been entered")
            assert True
            input_hostname.clear()
        except (Exception, NameError, AssertionError):
            allure.attach(driver.get_screenshot_as_png(), name="testLoginScreen", attachment_type=AttachmentType.PNG)
            logging.error('Error - url_input module', exc_info=True)
            assert False


    @allure.severity(allure.severity_level.CRITICAL)
    def test_url_checkbox1(self, url):
        wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, u1chb1)))
        u1chb1ch = driver.find_element_by_xpath(u1chb1).get_attribute('class')
        if u1chb1ch == 'passed':
            print(f"{url} - test_url_checkbox1 - PASS")
            assert True
        else:
            allure.attach(driver.get_screenshot_as_png(), name="testLoginScreen", attachment_type=AttachmentType.PNG)
            logging.error(f'{url} - checkbox 1 - FAILED', exc_info=True)
            assert False

    @allure.severity(allure.severity_level.CRITICAL)
    def test_url_checkbox2(self, url):
        wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, u1chb2)))
        u1chb2ch = driver.find_element_by_xpath(u1chb2).get_attribute('class')
        if u1chb2ch == 'passed':
            print(f"{url} - test_url_checkbox2 - PASS")
            assert True
        else:
            allure.attach(driver.get_screenshot_as_png(), name="testLoginScreen", attachment_type=AttachmentType.PNG)
            logging.error(f'{url} - checkbox 2 - FAILED', exc_info=True)
            assert False

    @allure.severity(allure.severity_level.CRITICAL)
    def test_url_checkbox3(self, url):
        wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, u1chb3)))
        u1chb3ch = driver.find_element_by_xpath(u1chb3).get_attribute('class')
        if u1chb3ch == 'passed':
            print(f"{url} - test_url_checkbox3 - PASS")
            assert True
        else:
            allure.attach(driver.get_screenshot_as_png(), name="testLoginScreen", attachment_type=AttachmentType.PNG)
            logging.error(f'{url} - checkbox 3 - FAILED', exc_info=True)
            assert False

    @allure.severity(allure.severity_level.CRITICAL)
    def test_url_checkbox4(self, url):
        wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, u1chb4)))
        u1chb4ch = driver.find_element_by_xpath(u1chb4).get_attribute('class')
        if u1chb4ch == 'passed':
            print(f"{url} - test_url_checkbox4 - PASS")
            assert True
        else:
            allure.attach(driver.get_screenshot_as_png(), name="testLoginScreen", attachment_type=AttachmentType.PNG)
            logging.error(f'{url} - checkbox 4 - FAILED', exc_info=True)
            assert False

    @allure.severity(allure.severity_level.CRITICAL)
    def test_url_checkbox5(self, url):
        wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, u1chb5)))
        u1chb5ch = driver.find_element_by_xpath(u1chb5).get_attribute('class')
        if u1chb5ch == 'passed':
            print(f"{url} - test_url_checkbox5 - PASS")
            assert True
        else:
            allure.attach(driver.get_screenshot_as_png(), name="testLoginScreen", attachment_type=AttachmentType.PNG)
            logging.error(f'{url} - checkbox 5 - FAILED', exc_info=True)
            assert False

    @allure.severity(allure.severity_level.CRITICAL)
    def test_url_checkbox6(self, url):
        wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, u1chb6)))
        u1chb6ch = driver.find_element_by_xpath(u1chb6).get_attribute('class')
        if u1chb6ch == 'passed':
            print(f"{url} - test_url_checkbox6 - PASS")
            assert True
        else:
            allure.attach(driver.get_screenshot_as_png(), name="testLoginScreen", attachment_type=AttachmentType.PNG)
            logging.error(f'{url} - checkbox 6 - FAILED', exc_info=True)
            assert False


    @allure.severity(allure.severity_level.NORMAL)
    def test_url_expdate_w(self, url):
        expdatech = driver.find_element_by_id(expdate).text
        if int(expdatech) > 7:
            print(f"{url} - expdate more than 7 days - PASS")
            assert True
        else:
            allure.attach(driver.get_screenshot_as_png(), name="testLoginScreen", attachment_type=AttachmentType.PNG)
            print(expdatech)
            logging.warning(f"{url} SSL certificate will expire in less than 7 days, days left: {expdatech}", exc_info=True)
            assert False


def test_close_browser():
    try:
        logger.info("Testing finished")
        driver.close()
        assert True
    except (Exception, NameError, AssertionError):
        logging.error('Error - close_browser module', exc_info=True)
        assert False
```

Result of first test: empty suite with conftest in comments and I have not knowledge hot to run it separately (tried to learn, but too hard for me for now).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the order of the items in the `pytest_collection_modifyitems` hook. If you put this in your `conftest.py`:

```py
def pytest_collection_modifyitems(config, items):
    def param_part(item):
        # check for the wanted module and test class
        if item.nodeid.startswith("test_urls.py::TestSSL::"):
            # find the start of the parameter part in the nodeid
            index = item.nodeid.find('[')
            if index > 0:
                # sort by parameter name
                return item.name[item.nodeid.index('['):]

        # for all other cases, sort by node id as usual
        return item.nodeid

    # re-order the items using the param_part function as key
    items[:] = sorted(items, key=param_part)
```

Here is the output of `pytest -vv` for your example:

```
================================================= test session starts =================================================
...
collected 6 items

test_paramtrize_order.py::Test01::test01[url0001] PASSED                                                         [ 16%]
test_paramtrize_order.py::Test01::test02[url0001] PASSED                                                         [ 33%]
test_paramtrize_order.py::Test01::test01[url0002] PASSED                                                         [ 50%]
test_paramtrize_order.py::Test01::test02[url0002] PASSED                                                         [ 66%]
test_paramtrize_order.py::Test01::test01[url0003] PASSED                                                         [ 83%]
test_paramtrize_order.py::Test01::test02[url0003] PASSED                                                         [100%]

================================================== 6 passed in 0.09s ==================================================
```

This will change the order only for the parametrized tests in the module `test_urls.py` and the class `TestSSL`. If you want to have this for more or all parametrized tests, you can adapt or remove the check in `param_part`.

Comment: Thank you! I'll try. And have you any idea how to do it in one file plaese?

Comment: You mean, without `conftest.py`? No, I don't know if this is possible. Do you have a problem with `conftest.py`?

Comment: I'm really new at automation and ask you to write in more detail how to apply that to one class, for now I can't solve this task, maybe you can help me with my current code (I apologize in advance for my mistakes or something). Updated the post-code with my real task.

Comment: I adapted the answer to check for the test module and class name and only re-order the tests for this class (you have to adapt it to your test, of course).

Comment: I really appreciate your help mister. I have to learn how to run separately modules in pytest now, but I think that it will work. I will add details after finish, just in case.

Comment: Looks like that I can't solve this: for now class running first, before all other tests and conftest sorts tests inside class by alphabet (not a big problem, but it is excess addiction). Looking for solution.

Comment: Well, this is not enough information for help. Either adapt this question, or write a new one with the information what you have done, what is the output, and what do you want.

Comment: It looks like it works, but partly and i don't have knowledge how to fix it.
Result tests of class running in almost right sequences, (sorted by alphabet, but iterates with one url as I needed). But after them running the first test (which should be first obviously, to let other continue and pass). https://prnt.sc/ttta14 - screenshot with current sequence of tests.
Is there way to run class without first priority and sort tests inside without dependence of test names on the alphabet?

Comment: You can order your tests a you want in `pytest_collection_modifyitems` - I just showed you how to do this for your initial question, that concerned the parametrized tests. You can do more ordering there, or can can try to use [pytest-ordering](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-ordering/) for ordering tests. Sorry, I didn't understand your requirement (without first priority) - the default sort order in pytest is always alphabetical order.

Comment: Also you may consider to write a new question (or checking existing ones), if you have more questions/requirements.

Comment: the current sequence is class> test before class, test after class, but I need a normal sequence: test before class> class with iterations> test after class (conftest sets the execution priority to the class, I can't figure out how to remove this priority)